# How can you automatically translate a page on load?

Tags: translation, bing, google-translate

Google Translate. Bing Translate. You can add a widget. You can select "Spanish" and the page will translate to Spanish.

I do not want to user to have to select "Spanish". I want the page to load in Spanish automatically.  Never mind why I want these things. They are necessary parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at `navigator.UserLanguage` in javascript.  It's not entirely foolproof, but it's a good starting point, and provided the users aren't messing with what the navigator object actually pulls (fairly easy to fake) it should give you a reasonably good start.....you don't really have what language(s) you're using on your page tagged, so it's sorta hard to provide specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341982.aspx#feedback